# jQuery click on text

Tags: jquery

I am developing a web application, where I have a table in an HTML table...

```
<table class="alphabet">
     <tr>
          <td>a</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>c</td>
     </tr>
</table>
```

I need to change the text color when I hover over each letter, I have the following code that works correctly:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $(".alphabet td").hover{
          function(){
               $(this).css('color', 'yellow');
          }, function(){
               $(this).css('color', 'white');
          }
     }
}
```

I need to implement another function where the color of the letter changes when I click on the letter. The issue is that I tried .click() but it didn't work. The color is pretty irrelevant, but lets say I need it to be red.

To add to the complexity, Let's say if I click the letter (changing it to red), when I hover over the letter it should change to yellow, but on leave, it should change back to red, not white.

I'm not asking for someone to implement it, I just need to know what method to call, like .hover(), or .click(), etc... Thanks in advanced!

UPDATE:
I am required to use jQuery for this project. I need use it because I need to do more then just change the color, I used the color as an example.

Comment: CSS is better suited to this sort of job. look at CSS pseudoclasses!

Comment: Probable solition is , you can maintain 3 different classes and try to apply it whenever required.

Comment: Well, I need to use jQuery. I need to do more stuff then just change the color, I just used the color change as an example.

Comment: If that is the case, you can listen to both the events. hover() and click()

Comment: I tried .click() but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery you should probably use $(selector).click() with $(selector).css({}).

If you're having trouble getting the colors to change, use your browser's CSS inheritance inspector to see if something else is overwriting it.

Also, have you tried CSS pseudoclass :hover?

e.g.

```
.myclass {
    color: red;
}
.myclass:hover {
    color: blue;
}
```

Comment: Well, I need to use jQuery. I need to do more stuff then just change the color, I just used the color change as an example.

Comment: @Kryptos why don't you add that information to your post? It will make it more applicable for others.

Comment: Updated my original post

Answer (score 0):

Your hover function is wrong that you are using .hover{} , so you need to use .hover() instead and I've set a flag to check if that td is clicked and if clicked do remain the color red:

```
var flag = false;
$(".alphabet td").hover(
          function(){
               $(this).css('color', 'yellow');
          }, function(){

              $(".alphabet td").click(function(){
                  $(this).css('color','red');
                  flag = true;
              });
              if(flag == false){
               $(this).css('color', 'white');
              }
          }
     );
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hwLDL/)